# Disabling submit if no checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a script to disable a submit button if nothing is checked but it does not seem to work if all boxes are unchecked after been checked.

Please see below:

```
$('.obstructions .panel').on('change', function() {

  //Disable button if none selected
  var anyBoxesChecked = false;
  $('form input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      anyBoxesChecked = true;
      $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  if (anyBoxesChecked == false) {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
  }

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need the HTML too. [mcve]